# Please explain the output to this code:

Tags: c, if-statement

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
   if(0xA)
   if(052)              
   if('\xeb')
   if('\012')              //what do the above 3 statements mean?
   printf("Hello World!")
   else;
   else;
   else;
   else;
 }
```

Output:
   Hello World!

so here, what is the meaning of 052, \xeb and \012?
And what is the significance of the multiple else statements?

Comment: This code is pretty meaningless - any value that isn't 0 is considered true, so those if statements are all effectively the same

Comment: Did you lose your debugger?

Comment: They all evaluate to true. `0` is false and all other values are true. `0xA` is hexadecimal, `052` is octal...

Comment: Where are you finding this junk, people?

Comment: Please open a good C book and learn the language. Besides, the above code is rubbish.

Comment: Since you are asking about this program, I'll assume that you didn't write it. May I suggest that you ask the author what he meant by it? Or, if you can't find the author, can you tell us where you found this program?

Comment: So this was a question asked in a MCQ test prep book. The topic covered till now is basic controls structures (which I have understood well) but the above code didn't make sense :/

Comment: Even for an 'academic' work, this is just dire:(

Comment: @N.Vakharia: throw that book in the trash immediately.  If it's a test prep book, then the only thing it's preparing you for is failure.

Comment: Haha! Duly noted! @John Bode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a trick question.  Presumably someone thought you could learn something from it.  Presumably this person also thinks that a good way to teach a child to ride a bicycle is to flatten the bicycle's tires, and put large boulders in the way, and randomly give the child a rough shove to the side, because it "builds character", and if you can learn to ride a bicycle in spite of those obstacles, you will eventually be a really good bike rider.  But I digress.

Anyway, here's an explanation of what's going on in that code.

`0xA` is a hexadecimal constant.  It has the value 0A<sub>16</sub>, or 10 (base 10).
`052` is an octal constant.  It has the value 52<sub>8</sub>, or 42 (base 10).
`'\xeb'` is a hexadecimal character constant.  It is a character with the value EB<sub>16</sub>, or 235 (base 10) (which in ISO-8859-1 or Unicode ends up being an e with two dots over it, ë).
`'\012'` is an ordinary, octal character constant.  It is a character with the value 12<sub>8</sub>, or 10 (base 10) (which in ASCII ends up being a newline character, `'\n'`).

When you say

```
if( expr )
```

in C, the expression is considered "true" if it is nonzero, or "false" if it is zero.  Needless to say, all four of those constants are nonzero.

The full syntax of an `if` statement in C is either

```
if( expr )
    statement-or-block
```

or

```
if( expr )
    statement-or-block
else
    statement-or-block
```

where `statement-or-block` is either a single statement, or a "block" (sequence) of multiple statements enclodes in braces `{ }`.

A little-used piece of syntax in C is the "empty statement".  If you have nothing, followed by a semicolon, that's an empty statement, and it does... nothing.

It is considered mandatory in polite circles to indent your code to portray its structure.  So the normal way of presenting this code would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    if(0xA)
        if(052)              
            if('\xeb')
                if('\012')
                    printf("Hello World!")
                else
                    ;
            else
                ;
        else
            ;
    else
        ;
}
```

And, again, all four expressions evaluate immediately to "true".  So, in English, this code says "If true, then if true, then if true, then if true, then print 'Hello world!', else do nothing, else do nothing, else do nothing, else do nothing."

Phrased that way it sounds pretty stupid, I know.  And in fact, it's just as stupid in C as it is in English.

P.S. Besides the bizarre and unnecessary conditionals, another problem with the code as posted, which I have quietly corrected, is that it declared `main` as `void`, which is something else that's not done in polite circles, and throws further doubt on the validity of the book this code came from.

Answer (score 3):

From the C Standard (6.8.4.1 The if statement)

> 2 In both forms, **the first substatement is executed if the
>   expression compares unequal to 0**. In the else form, the second
>   substatement is executed if the expression compares equal to 0. If the
>   first substatement is reached via a label, the second substatement is
>   not executed.

So as each expression in the if statements

```
   if(0xA)
   if(052)              
   if('\xeb')
   if('\012')
```

are unequal to 0 then the enclosed call of the function printf (provided that a semicolon is present)

```
printf("Hello World!");
```

is executed.

So the if statements do not make much sense.

`0xA` is a hexadecimal integer constant equal to decimal 10

`052` is octal integer constant equal to decimal 42

`'\xeb'` is a character constant specified as a hexadecimal escape sequence

`'\012'` is a character constant specified as an octal escape sequence

Take into account that according to the C Standard the function `main` without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

Thus as each expression of the if statements is not equal to 0 then the program is in fact equivalent to the following program

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    printf("Hello World!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted is equivalent to

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main( void ) // void main() is not a standard signature
{
   if(0xA)
   {
     if(052)  
     {            
       if('\xeb')
       {
         if('\012')          
         {    
           printf("Hello World!")
         }
         else
         {
         }
       }
       else
       {
       }
     }
     else
     {
     }
   }
   else
   {
   }
}
```

Curly braces can be omitted if there is only a single statement within them:

```
if ( a )
{
  do_something();
}
```

can be written as

```
if ( a )
  do_something();
```

although I and others recommend against doing this except in specific cases.

An `if` statement itself counts as a single statement, so it's possible to write

```
if ( a )
{
  if ( b )
    do_something();
}
```

as

```
if ( a )
  if ( b )
    do_something();
```

And, of course, the compiler doesn't care about indentation, so

```
if ( a )
if ( b )
do_something();
```

means the same thing - however, as you've discovered, code written this way is a little hard to understand.

The test condition of an `if`, `while`, or `for` may be any scalar type (integer, floating-point, or pointer value).  C didn't originally have a distinct Boolean type, so the rule is any non-zero value in a Boolean context evaluates to "true", while zero evaluates to "false".

Each of `0xA`, `052`, `'\xeb'`, and `'\012'` is a scalar expression with a non-zero value (`0xA` and `052` are integer literals in hexadecimal and octal format, respectively, while `'\xeb'` and `'\012'` are escape sequences representing character values in hex and octal format), so the bodies of all the `if` statements are executed.

You have four nested `if` statements, and only the innermost one is doing anything interesting.  The `else` clauses are empty and can be omitted entirely:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main( void ) 
{
   if(0xA)
   {
     if(052)  
     {            
       if('\xeb')
       {
         if('\012')          
         {    
           printf("Hello World!")
         }
       }
    }
}
```

And, as I said above, the curly braces may be omitted as well:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main( void ) 
{
   if(0xA)
     if(052)  
       if('\xeb')
         if('\012')          
           printf("Hello World!")
}
```

All of which reduces to

```
int main( void ) 
{
  printf("Hello World!")
}
```

A reasonably smart compiler won't bother generating the machine code for the `if` statements at all, and should generate machine code *as though* the program had been written as above.